# Im trying to create a role based login system

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code im using currently, I have the role based system working on my register page but it does not work when i try and log in

I've tried using the catch function to try and get user data and then put it in a condition but that did not work. Im expecting it to navigate to certain pages depending on the role of the user.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/components/my_button.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/components/my_textfield.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/components/square_tile.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/pages/admin_page.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/pages/bookstore.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/pages/register_page.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/services/AuthService.dart';
import 'forgot_pw_page.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void navigateBasedOnRole(BuildContext context, Role selectedRole) {
  if (selectedRole == Role.admin) {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdminPage()),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  } else {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Bookstore()),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  }
}
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function()? onTap;
  LoginPage({super.key, required this.onTap});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // text editing controllers
  final emailController = TextEditingController();

  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  // sign user in method
  void signUserIn() async {

    //show loading circle 
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
    );


    try {await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text, 
      password: passwordController.text
      );
       //pop the loading circle
      Navigator.pop(context);

      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
         //pop the loading circle
         Navigator.pop(context);
        if(e.code == 'user-not-found'){
          print("No user found");
          //show error to user 
          wrongEmailMessage();
          }
        else if (e.code == 'wrong-password'){
          print("Wrong Password");
          //show error to user 
          wrongPasswordMessage();

        }  

    }
   
  }

    // wrong email message pop up
    void wrongEmailMessage(){
     showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return const AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Incorrect Email'),
      );
     },
     );
    }
    // wrong Password message pop up
    void wrongPasswordMessage(){
     showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return const AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Incorrect Password'),
      );
     },
     );
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
          
                // logo
                const Icon(
                  Icons.lock,
                  size: 100,
                ),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
          
                // welcome back, you've been missed!
                Text(
                  'Welcome back you\'ve been missed!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 25),
          
                // email textfield
                MyTextField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  obscureText: false,
                ),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
          
                // password textfield
                MyTextField(
                  controller: passwordController,
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
          
                //  password?
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                          context, 
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context)
                            {
                            return ForgotPasswordPage();
                          },
                          ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Forgot Password?',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 25),
          
                // sign in button
                MyButton(
                  text: 'Sign In',
                  onTap: signUserIn,
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 50),

                //or continue with
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Expanded(child: Divider(
                    thickness: 0.5,
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
                  ),
                
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Or continue with',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                      ),
                  ),
                    
                    Expanded(
                      child: Divider
                      (
                    thickness: 0.5,
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
                  ),
                  ],
                
                  ),
                ), 
                const SizedBox(height: 50,),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                  SquareTile(
                    onTap: () => AuthService().signInWithGoogle(),
                    imagePath: 'lib/images/google.png',  ),

                  SizedBox(width: 25,),
                  
                  SquareTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      
                    },
                    imagePath: 'lib/images/apple.png',),
                ],
                  ),
                
                const SizedBox(height: 50,),

                // not a member? register now
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Not a member?',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 4),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: widget.onTap,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Register now',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you storing the user Role information? The code provided that not show where that information is retrieved from.

Answer (score 2):

Simple just save the userCredentails that u get from function `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword` and then call your function `navigateBasedOnRole`

like:

```
UserCredentail userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
navigateBasedOnRole(context, userCredential.user?.role);
```

hopefully that helps

Comment: sorry im very new to flutter can u write the function please

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is obvious! You have created this method: `navigateBasedOnRole`, but you have not used it anywhere in your code.
Here is what you should do:

1. if the login was successful, get the user ID.
2. fetch the user role based on the ID.
3. navigate between the pages based on that role.